# Cant able to Create Package.JSON file with NPM init on Mac

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I can't able to create the package.json with the NPM init.

Here is the log data I got.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'init', '--yes' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.0
4 silly package data undefined
5 info init written successfully
6 verbose stack Error: Invalid name: "Donateers  Tailwind Test"
6 verbose stack     at ensureValidName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:336:15)
6 verbose stack     at Object.fixNameField (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:215:5)
6 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:32:38
6 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
6 verbose stack     at normalize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:31:15)
6 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:429:5)
6 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:161:5)
6 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:382:12
6 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
6 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
7 verbose cwd /Users/sureshkumar/Documents/GitHub/Donateers  Tailwind Test
8 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
9 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "init" "--yes"
10 verbose node v14.16.0
11 verbose npm  v6.14.11
12 error Invalid name: "Donateers  Tailwind Test"
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

I did tried Sudo too.

```
 sudo npm init -y
```

The idea is to avoid all the questions. It's for the tailwindCSS setup.

Thank you

Comment: Rename your directory from `Donateers  Tailwind Test` to e.g. `donateers-tailwind-test` - essentially remove the spaces and make it lowercase. Then `cd` to that newly named directory and run `npm init -y`

Comment: Thank you Rob. 

That's exactly I did now and it solved the issue. 

Appreciate the quick help.